# How to disable Grails Spring plugins at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, grails, grails-plugin, cas

I have a situation where I need to declare the [Grails Spring Security CAS plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-cas) as a compile-time dependency like so (in my Grails app's `BuildConfig.groovy`):

```
plugins {
    // Other plugins omitted for brevity...

    compile ":spring-security-cas:1.0.5"
}
```

However, depending on logic that I don't have available to my app until runtime, I need to dynamically disable/re-enable the plugin on the fly, at runtime.

Is this possible to do? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: have you read the documentation for the plugin configuration and tried changing the configuration value of cas.active at runtime through your application?

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore - I did see that, however I guess that's the root of my question (I'm brand-spanking-new to Grails): how do I, from some arbitrary POJO, read/write that value of `cas.active`?

Comment: To change configuration values at runtime you have to get a reference to GrailsApplication. Typically you do this using dependency injection **GrailsApplication grailsApplication** and then you can modify anything you like from grailsApplication.config.x.y.z ... Now the trick will be, this plugin may or may not respect you changing that value at runtime. If it does not you may have to look into how the plugin handles a configuration reload event (see the plugin source code on github) and mimic that event in your own code as well. What you are doing is not typical in Grails apps.

Comment: Thanks again @JoshuaMoore - last question: where would the plugin define a "configuration reload event"?

Comment: Typically it would be an onChange event in the plugin descriptor. See: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-cas/blob/master/SpringSecurityCasGrailsPlugin.groovy and http://www.cacoethes.co.uk/blog/groovyandgrails/supporting-reloading-in-your-grails-plugins

Comment: Thanks again @JoshuaMoore - so I notice that there isn't any `onChange` event defined in that source file. What does that say to you? That this pugin doesn't support reloading (and hence won't honor runtime changes to `cas.active`)?

Comment: That's it exactly. As Jeff points out in his quazi-answer this is likely due to the fact it's doing a lot of configuration of spring beans and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer is no.  There is nothing in Grails that allows you to express anything like "if a certain system property is set, completely disable some particular plugin".  Grails plugins can do a lot of things that could not be undone or redone at runtime.  For example, a plugin can modify web.xml at build time.

Plugins can be written such that they interrogate the environment at runtime and behave differently based on that, but that is up to the plugin author to have accounted for that.  Some plugin behavior can also be modified at runtime by interacting with beans in the Spring application context.  It really depends on the plugin and what kind of behavior you are trying to turn on and off.